# How to use UltraVNC on Ubuntu desktop which is running on VMWARE

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, vnc

**My systems**

**Host:** Windows 10 X64 Pro

**Guest :** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running on VMware Workstation 12 Player(Free)

I have done below steps.

1. Install VMware tools for guest.
2. Follow the guide [How to Install and Configure VNC on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04)
3. Download and install latest version of [UltraVNC for Windows](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html)
4. Connect to guest machine.

But I can't get the guest desktop or any terminal window.
I can only see the blank screen on UltraVNC as attached image below.

**How I can fix this to remote control my Ubuntu guest ?**

[UltraVNC error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m29u4.png)

Comment: I noticed that XtightVNC is connection to display :1. Are you trying to connect to the display the guest "user" sees on the "monitor", or are you trying to create a new X session that is not on the guest "monitor"? Should the display :1 be display :0?

Comment: Do a `echo $DISPLAY` on the guest, Ubuntu, machine to verify what display you are looking at.

Comment: for `echo $DISPLAY` it's return :0

Comment: @jc__ I am trying to create a new X session which is not current guest monitor. It's should show as new screen with some buttons or terminal like that guide said.

Comment: Okay so you do NOT want you VNC session (:1) to interact with the session on the "monitor" (:0). It looks like Xorg or you desktop has not started for display :1 when you VNC in.

Comment: A couple of things to help trouble shoot: Boot your Ubuntu to a command line, not GUI. The command you execute to start the GUI is the command that VNC server must execute. (startx, startxfce4...) The help you are using stores the VNC server config in the home directory. Does that mean that user must be logged in before you VNC connect? You could move the VNC config files out of home and start the VNC server at the display manager. (lightDM, GDM, LXDM) this will allow you to VNC in and then login to the guest with any valid user.

Comment: @jc__ I was able to connect to the VNC server as your suggestion.